# How to set X-FRAME-OPTIONS header in Jboss?

Tags: iframe, jboss, jboss7.x, x-frame-options

I need load a HTML file in a iframe but i get the next error:

Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/xxxxxx/resources/xxxxx.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

¿How do I set X-FRAME-OPTIONS header in my Jboss Server? I think I must do it in standalone.xml file but I'm not sure.

Thanks!